# Hash compare always return false

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have checked all other answers but nothing is working , does not matter what ever string I provide it always returns false.

```
import hashlib

class User:
    def __init__(self, username,password):
        self.username = username
        ''' Password will be encrypted , create user'''
        self.password = self._encrypt_pw(password)
        self.is_logged = False

    def _encrypt_pw(self,password):
        'encrypt password and return SHA'
        hash_string = (self.username+password)
        hash_string = hash_string.encode("utf-8")
        return hashlib.sha256(hash_string).hexdigest

    def check_password(self,password):
        'return true if password is true for this user or false'
        encrypted = self._encrypt_pw(password)
        return encrypted == self.password
```

Below is the code run.

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from user import User
>>> u = User("abc","abc")
>>> u.password
<built-in method hexdigest of _hashlib.HASH object at 0x036BBCC8>
>>> u.password()
'bbb59da3af939f7af5f360f2ceb80a496e3bae1cd87dde426db0ae40677e1c2c'
>>> u.check_password("abc")
False
```

When I 
put

```
return encrypted.digest() == self.password.digest(),
```

it returns error

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'digest'
```

Comment: So, `u.password` is a `<built-in method hexdigest of _hashlib.HASH object at ...>`. Basically, it's a _function_. Do you want it to be a function? Why do you think it became a function? Hint: take a look at this line: `return hashlib.sha256(hash_string).hexdigest`.

Comment: Holy Moly! Thank You. Its working now.